# getJson after getJson not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, getjson

I'm trying to make a request when the button is clicked.

If it is the first time clicking it, I make a getJson to get an array with the IDs for the second request.

The problem is, when it makes the first request, it stops right before the second request, so I have to click again to make the second request.

Here is my script code:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var IDs = new Array();
    var iterator = 0;
    // When id with Action is clicked
    $("#Action").click(function() {
        if(IDs.length <= 0){
            // Load generator.php as JSON and assign to the data variable
            $.getJSON('generator.php', {tags : "lol"},  function(data) {
                IDs = data.value;               
            });
        }

        //PAGE STOPS HERE

        $.getJSON('imagem.php', {ids : IDs[iterator]}, function(data) {
            iterator++;
            document.title = "IMG2";

            $("#Imagem").html(data.value);  
            if(iterator > IDs.length-1)
                iterator = 0;
        });

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: The second one is called when page loads, you need to call it after click, you can place it inside function

Comment: The second one depends on the first one, and both should be loaded when the button is clicked. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: yes you are right, both included inside click function :)

Comment: The 2nd `$.getJSON` call needs to be put *inside* the 1st one's callback.  The 2nd one will be ran *before* `IDs` is populated.  Remember, AJAX is *asynchronous*!

Comment: If you use correct indentation these thing are much easier to see.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. @MarcelKorpel where can I learn the correct identation?

Comment: Look at the corrected version I provided (or put your script in http://jsbeautifier.com); in short, indent after `{`, unindent before `}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$.getJson()` function is asynchronous. This means that when it executes that bit of code, it continues on with execution. The second call depends on the first one so should be nested in the success callback like this:

```
$.getJSON('generator.php', {tags : "lol"},  function(data) {
   IDs = data.value;               

   $.getJSON('imagem.php', {ids : IDs[iterator]}, function(data) {
      iterator++;
      document.title = "IMG2";

      $("#Imagem").html(data.value);  
      if(iterator > IDs.length-1)
         iterator = 0;
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because $getJSON is an async event, so both your $getJSON function calls are happening at once, and your second requires results from the first.  Please use the success event from jquery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

example from the above website:

```
$.getJSON("example.json", function() {
  alert("success");
})
.success(function() { alert("second success"); });
```

New Code:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var IDs = new Array();
        var iterator = 0;
        // When id with Action is clicked
        $("#Action").click(function() {
            if(IDs.length <= 0){
                // Load generator.php as JSON and assign to the data variable
                $.getJSON('generator.php', {tags : "lol"},  function(data) {
                    IDs = data.value;
                }).success(function() {
                    $.getJSON('imagem.php', {ids : IDs[iterator]}, function(data) {
                        iterator++;
                        document.title = "IMG2";

                        $("#Imagem").html(data.value);  
                        if(iterator > IDs.length-1)
                                iterator = 0;
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code visiting, we think -

It is a typical case of ajax call ...

to make the 2nd call after 1st call, you should call the 2nd getjson within 1st getjson callback to make this working  - i.e. -

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    var IDs = new Array();
                    var iterator = 0;
                    // When id with Action is clicked
                    $("#Action").click(function() {
                        if(IDs.length <= 0){
                        // Load generator.php as JSON and assign to the data variable
                        $.getJSON('generator.php', {tags : "lol"},  function(data) {
                            IDs = data.value;               
                            $.getJSON('imagem.php', {ids : IDs[iterator]}, function(data) {
                            iterator++;
                            document.title = "IMG2";

                            $("#Imagem").html(data.value);  
                            if(iterator > IDs.length-1)
                                    iterator = 0;
                        });


                        });
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

I have faced same situation before, for ajax calling in different applications. Hope this help you.